# Set DB name in SQL Server stored procedure so that it can be set at the beginning of the script and not for every update statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I've created a stored procedure which should overwrite/update some column values in a database. The reason for that is that it's a backup from PROD to our TEST environment and I want to overwrite path/folder locations to another location as the PROD environment.

The database name can be different every time and I would like to set it only once in my stored procedure, just to prevent that I have to set it for every update statement.

So I did something like here below, but this is not accepted by SSMS:

```
DECLARE @DBNAME NVARCHAR(50)
SET @DBNAME = 'TEST'

UPDATE @DBNAME.[DBO].[SomeTable]
SET [code] = 'SomeCode'

UPDATE @DBNAME.[DBO].[AnotherTable]
SET [code] = 'AnotherCode'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I'm declaring it as a `NVARCHAR` variable?

Comment: Why do you need to put the database name in the name at all? Why not just connect to the correct database? Then you can just use 2 part naming.

Comment: The database will be dropped and recreated. So the Stored Procedure will be created on the master database. Eventually I want to use the stored procedure in a Powershell, #C, CMD command or something and set the DB name with a param. People who want to update the values in the database have to run it outside SSMS.

Comment: Creating it in the `master` database also sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parameterize identifiers in T-SQL.
You'll have to write your procedure as dynamic SQL.
Assuming the rest of the procedure (including the data) is static, this can be very simple:

```
DECLARE @DBNAME sysname, -- See below about sysname
        @SQL varchar(4000);
SET @DBNAME = 'TEST'

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE '+ @DBNAME +'.[DBO].[SomeTable]
SET [code] = ''SomeCode''' -- note the duplication of the ' char to escape it
EXEC(@SQL)

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE '+ @DBNAME +'.[DBO].[AnotherTable]
SET [code] = ''AnotherCode'''
EXEC(@SQL)
```

It gets a bit more cumbersome when you want to handle parameters correctly, but it's not really that complicated or hard.

One pro tip when it comes to dynamic SQL - You want to start by printing it before executing, and paste it into your query window, just so it will be easier to make sure it does what it's designed to do.

From [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> sysname is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is functionally equivalent to nvarchar(128), except that it isn't nullable. sysname is used to reference database object names.

Comment: QUOTENAME(@DBNAME)  is your friend.

Comment: Yeah, I was too lazy to add that